# file_get_contents returns strange characters with some Wikipedia pages, why?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have gone through most of the solutions but they all didn't work.

I try to parse a Wikipedia page using file_get_contents but the return differs according to something in the page I haven't figure out yet.

For example when I use it with this page, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word it works fine, but when I use it with this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Kolb it returns strage characters..

And both pages they're just the same, I guess.

What could be the problem ?

UPDATE 1

Here what I got :

```
î²$'ˆ‰ÃBÿ—¾XP·o€Ô%4aºäÇ$ÊãÔ¼s¾w>ÈÙfb%¾ Â“p£+Ïü J£x&6ç>vŸŠ$B­fbðzÊ~ìð¥³ˆè`lƒW{·²±Ÿd³žç"U™ðrÉ¥ý4ÃŠ'ú™,N—î, ¢©ª3/U+þÔGQãDý|A*¬iœø=céOy(èO€O‡ù4O3ø Ãvi_éÉ_/£K]x¢‘~~(Cp†(Q€!A£Ë±í‘åÀr\9¨N%G‘¼¸äav-ÍÁÖe€.ˆK¨È*Å/`ºøÏÄRž„¸ÔÞÉ‰œÁ'PQ‚€Ç©Å!¿Ô$g•f|œêbT-< ŸLÑUÌ` ¡Òâ4–L¢0Èv'Ö­SA€a?(Ù œ‚n÷ç€Pj°Ï4ê18·&À3þcXfÕ3pb éÌ:õ ”š˜egfTCã¦$Nñ˜Êó1õ^”æãÀO‹¹f‘«~Ø€Ø.°ñéyt!kñí­½ÉXôzÀåºÛ»Û[wl¹Ûã‡{Ûn¿+·S1½§ ráõËàEs?EÆIóå“¬Äè  3e,™K´Ô€`‘(Ï‘Zû©–q%$à ¯ÖDÄ @k5Ó¬þì§9ô ~rüÑó-Ï@{ÅFÒF ƒ—Ï­}Æ~`Kæâú1ÚŠJ2ér”OJäü˜Ã.zç ÜŸ‰ ¦§äMÀø<ÕL•$íL©Ö)¿v´€8„ÊÄqÁ·¡ƒC&_`~È–Ð’E!™zÔCŒŠÈ¶Pï³ë9 Éµaµ «' U¢„šY… E¸ç%V!N9ãÁ:º$iËòŠ¯™ªÀ€-…ž©0eÈªpê¥-¡hè³$="0   ²|>G-§Ð/Ê9'/ÂhJ>Í‚àY‚¸çQ‰?G¸üŸ±  B‚¡I5 ¨Îä|]/,„bA³©÷FdÑêßQÔAÊ‘*Á¦¨˜i†d•¡c^.ÒRÐLÔê˜¢,ŠÛ„}"…igÓI\/áÝ]üøsTwà­DH…"i°€PWI´€¦ýMå¨Sí%G„)y"º/´(,þ˜âKÙß“%ð”v‘4HUNÚ“ù­´:| m>Ò\a_Ò,g  ] !a4Ëƒ2ÇHÀ¾vÀiŒB×¥"Ø‡Ä•ê‚!½qÄý{ªÈÞ5UJ°¯•‚rý¶Ö¬"Ü[Ô^ÒrK,GYCiàçõÂóJÅˆšµÂ2&QÕt(5T 7 wv"å,¬06dI¹Os¶Ë3i‡•[#Á îÕÚªÃ•UujçåfµäÚ"èÑÒ—Œ‡žiZ5@dã1Ø6.”‹ZîÔ£b’•-Ð]²–tûq¯ÕI©ÊÖR+ÍÇ†í§­…·0[M”USoIì´±m<’˜KªÕŠp<çÁìr”LÓ†b•7‘Vºñ–ºÄ¥Ï‰E“eT,m¹º/Óna\É‚^A‡ª¤_+Ùª•l×Jvj%j%»µ’½ZÉÃZI¯[/ªCÝ«ƒÝ«ÃÝ«Þ«CÞë6Ùm³[‡¿×…¬U—k»¾ÛÛõåØm˜ënÃd÷úõ÷úÅÒI-»¥]Û„Ïª¬æ·+ŸEÙºOŠ’Â—n—t»t¾<KT3(½çÑçÍOøßÆ£ÕúM†Fo³z#«”vƒì@È|ÿZr3U¦}MÈÓì¢_àþˆî`!¶wLvxÿAOìî=Üív» ÃÆãÝÉdÒwû¾c©x×¸]ÕàŸõwN\@6ÑV~^˜Y-ê€¿Ñ¯ÜTÇ?ò+‡´fhKWÊ‘r¥È*ãs4FŒ²D(Cz{[FbÛ0íL½ƒá„ÒøhyB¯ !Í·¤ØÞÂ >‘QtP^j+fáßDJdÞÓQ…”{Â`Âþ½Vë?aAÆNž°ÝC\Pá.4G;nš:Ãqä-?Å (äI°Ž1-´}·e¢¼ŠÓtäâ‹3ôj´    Ú ²:Ÿµ»ÿÞ;ÐýÉ‡V¦ ÂÕ8†h›ýÈ†ÏOZø&×Åÿœ@3Ž¶-å§#7C Z&£„-”L‰>‚*™‰ç|   F‰3\ûæ›}Ï¿d¾£.¤¨Á4±õ0Š1N…k íªíöÛÃ"ëƒÛ]¨bó6t‰ëà0@Ø´ÇÆoö9µGÅzæ²ÌäcÚc4¥ð5-òZ `‚-)ŠóÈ‚ÿL¸®!á¥«è«$Ê:„$ìÈFcl®ésí›‚$É[³Î¾»ï¿Ûd¯bŸFSJ/ ù<�5s}ãûÌ€L,*1S!Ø:õ‰è*ÒÍŸIµÝLrÖ£9ÚufÊ…&ç¦ƒ•N™<Ï"§œW A5ârÏ«qp¬Á->*!D±òV£§¢^Ëø5m3ÇÒnåcgø4‰æ·Èð0ˆ á¬ö[ èþèû¨¨ð–­õW{ÍþGMÐNÉ¢z·XÞÊ¢*¥I`±^ŒŸà7Ë¢ìLyõœo-:CxÕŸ’}d²É*íâ–R‡ò¯¦¥oj³¨Àh*pƒÊÔ\¦DU×Bîé\—µcµÅâá>™ºÖWî™K•’5@_“Ým£Åª¿¬°­øê[ø^6ôûbþÓ\.Ý-ÃCó¶Æb‰Âªf%º1¾Ÿy €àNß@o:¡ 1Pê4 ‹y 7™èl}êb ™4%³[ô<Ñ°‡7üù”ñ€bðJøå1ExËâÏ8í:*™£#:¢Û©vNKpàô@Ác3.xØí“Ìƒßïd(r:YRŸíŒ¥n„âLð¦Ib’ÁG   .... (it goes on).
```

Comment: You want to post what these *strange characters* are?

Comment: Looks like compressed response to me. Can you try `gzopen() + gzread()` instead of `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: I tried them both, actually it throws an error in both pages, but the first page seem okay since it returns the whole string of the page, while the second one still have the problem since it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you show the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like compressed response to me. To get plain text response, you can use [`gzopen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.gzopen.php) + [`gzread()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.gzread.php):

```
$fp = gzopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Kolb', 'r');

$contents = '';
while ($chunk = gzread($fp, 256000)) {
    $contents .= $chunk;
}

gzclose($fp);
```

...or you can use `file_get_contents()`, but force server to return plain text:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0, compress;q=0\r\n",
    )
));

$contents = file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Kolb', false, $context);
```

...but not all servers take this into account, so I suggest you using [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.curl.php) for your task:

```
function get_url($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
}

$data = get_url('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word');
$data = get_url('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Kolb');
```

Comment: Looks like wikipedia does not take into account the `Accept-Encoding` header, so the second approach is not feasible.

Comment: The first one worked!!! so what was the problem ?? is it compression ? and how did you get to this solution ?

Comment: @Fahd Yes, glat it helped :)

Comment: When I use it with (wiki/Word) page it returns an error (failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden), so I will make it in the else caluse.. but what exactly is the difference between these two pages ?

Comment: First link served in plain text, but the second one is gzipped. But I can't tell the reason. It's weird that you receive an error for uncompressed page, it works well for me.

Comment: Is there a way to tell, in advance, weather the page is compressed or not ?

Comment: You can ask server to give you uncompressed page, but not all servers take this into account (that's Wikipedia's case). You can also use cURL extension to load pages, I'll add an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it may be an encoding issue. Try converting the encoding and see if this helps.

```
mb_convert_encoding($wikitext, 'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($wikitext, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
```

The `file_get_contents` function apparently has some issues with non UTF-8 encoding according to it's reference page on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) this function was recommended there.

Comment: it just gives the same output. (UPDATE: I mean same as strange characters, but they look different :)

Comment: If you open the page in a browser are the strange characters still there? They may be control characters that your editor does not print but represents with strange characters, such as a diagonal with a question mark for some windows editors.

Comment: Editra, and Chrome for implementation and testing.

Comment: I would suggest specifying UTF-8 encoding with Editra before you open it.

Comment: I don't think the problem with Editra, I've been using it for 6 months for coding this project and it works fine with hundreds of Wikipedia pages.

Comment: @Fahd take a look at my comment on the question :)

Answer (score -1):

use this format:

```
file_get_contents(urlencode($url));
```

Edit 1:

I used below code and it worked http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yej-xwa

```
<?php
$url='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Kolb';
echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: it says : Message: file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDavid_A._Kolb) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: I used exactly the same code you wrote, though it worked for me in phpfiddle.org ... really strage!